# Sorting numbers in range

Tags: python, sorting

I am working on a python project and I need help to sort a list of elements.

It is a list with investment portfolios returns (10000 items). I want to sort them in intervals so that I can, then, assign probabilities to it.

Basically, I want to say that, for example, I'll have:

[image]

Could you help me out with a library/code that could do this sorting?

thanks

Comment: Do you want to sort it by probability or return range?

Comment: If it's stored as a list of tuples, you can just use `list.sort(key = lambda a: a[0])`

Comment: Or just `list.sort()` -- tuples automatically sort by the first element.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

```
import random
import numpy as np

ranges = [2e6, 2.5e6, 3e6, 3.5e6, 4e6, 4.5e6, 5e6]
returns = [random.randint(2e6, 5e6) for _ in range(10000)]

_, counts = np.unique(np.digitize(returns, bins=ranges), return_counts=True)
```

---

**Long Answer**

If I understand your question right, you want to count the number of elements in a list, given a condition. Assuming you pick the ranges yourself, a pure Python solution could look like this:

```
import random

returns = [random.randint(2e6, 5e6) for _ in range(10000)]
ranges = [[2e6, 2.5e6], [2.5e6, 3e6], [3.5e6, 4e6], [4e6, 4.5e6], [4.5e6, 5e6]]

print(f"Probability \t Return Range")
for lower, upper in ranges:
    returns_in_range = sum(1 for r in returns if lower <= r < upper)
    probability = 100 * (returns_in_range / len(returns))
    print(f"{probability :.2f}% \t\t {lower / 1e6 :.1f}M - {upper / 1e6 :.1f}M")
```

Which outputs something like:

```
Probability      Return Range
17.36%           2.0M - 2.5M
16.18%           2.5M - 3.0M
17.13%           3.5M - 4.0M
16.35%           4.0M - 4.5M
16.35%           4.5M - 5.0M
```

This is a simple solution, however it iterates over the returns once for every range, which is costly in your case. A better way is to iterate over the returns once and keep a counter for every range.

```
import random

ranges = [[2e6, 2.5e6], [2.5e6, 3e6], [3.5e6, 4e6], [4e6, 4.5e6], [4.5e6, 5e6]]
returns = [random.randint(2e6, 5e6) for _ in range(10000)]

counts = [0] * len(ranges)
for ret in returns:
    for idx, (lower, upper) in enumerate(ranges):
        if lower <= ret < upper:
            counts[idx] += 1

# print the results
print(f"Probability \t Return Range")
for idx, (lower, upper) in enumerate(ranges):
    returns_in_range = counts[idx]
    probability = 100 * (returns_in_range / len(returns))
    print(f"{probability :.2f}% \t\t {lower / 1e6 :.1f}M - {upper / 1e6 :.1f}M")
```

Using a library like `numpy` may increase performance significantly, as it is mostly written in C. The operation you are trying to do is called [binning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning) and can be implemented like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np

ranges = [2e6, 2.5e6, 3e6, 3.5e6, 4e6, 4.5e6, 5e6]
returns = [random.randint(2e6, 5e6) for _ in range(10000)]

_, counts = np.unique(np.digitize(returns, bins=ranges), return_counts=True)

# print the results
print(f"Probability \t Return Range")
for idx, (lower, upper) in enumerate(zip(ranges, ranges[1:])):
    probability = 100 * (counts[idx] / len(returns))
    print(f"{probability :.2f}% \t\t {lower / 1e6 :.1f}M - {upper / 1e6 :.1f}M")
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked!